# Where can I find the aerofoil geometry of a commercial aircraft so as to design it in CAD software?

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation, airfoil

As a part of my final year thesis, I need to design a commercial aerofoil for an existing aircraft (such as Boeing/Airbus) to conduct some FEA & CFD analysis. I've been trying to source aerofoil geometry so as to design it on CAD tools, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Note: I've gone through airfoiltools.com and I was looking for more than just the NACA Airfoil. I was hoping I could get the complete airfoil geometry including that of the spars, ribs, skin, slats, ailerons, spoilers & tanks. I've even tried going through the TCDS Database, but I haven't found any relevant information there.

Comment: Is your assignment to *design* an aerofoil, or to draw an existing one? You shouldn't need any existing aerofoil info to design a new one, especially for a school project.

Answer (score 4):

All the current manufacturers develop proprietary airfoils combined with wing planform, washout, etc. using CFD for optimum pressure distribution, low drag, high critical Mach number, high maximum CL, benign stall propagation and benign aeroelastic characteristics. That applies to Boeing, Bombardier, Embraer and Airbus.
This type of info is not normally released by the manufacturers.
TCDS's do not have this kind of data.
You can do your own research starting with a standard NACA airfoils like those found in NACA report 640(Summary of Airfoil Data) and modifying them.

Comment: Also modern wings generally don't have a set airfoil shape, they are continuously varied from root to tip. Older wings may have set of airfoil shapes each placed at stations along the span and connected by basic geometries. (shapes suitable for real world materials used in manufacturing)